# Drag and Drop from outlook into a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, outlook

Is there a way to drag and drop an email from Outlook to a Silverlight application? I am able to drag and drop an email from Outlook on to the desktop and then on to the Silverlight Application but it doesn't seem possible to do a direct drag and drop on to the silverlight app. Also, will this be possible in Silverlight 5?

Comment: no end user understands that while they can drag mails to desktop and explorer, and drag files from explorer to silverlight, why cannot they drag mails to silverlight? six years later and still no solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: no.   **Silverlight** (*including Silverlight 5*) only supports Drag-drop where the payload type supports `FileDrop`.  Outlook is not generating a drag drop format that supports `FileDrop` so a drag from Outlook cannot be supported in Silverlight.

Comment: there are businesses inventing fixes for this shortcoming, https://outlook2web.com and others. The Internet Explorer team [blames it on Outlook](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/867235/html5-fileapi-file-input-does-not-support-dragging-and-dropping-from-outlook), and they closed the ticket with a [nice "WON'T FIX" status](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/212440). New attempt [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10716512)